# WordPress Changing Active Tab Text Color and Header Height

Tags: css, wordpress

I have some problems with WordPress on a Page I'm designing
I would like to change it's header height and the active page text color

Here's a screenshot: 
https://s31.postimg.cc/gvpiz9lm3/firefox_2018-04-26_15-08-06.png

What's the code I can use?

Thanks.

Comment: The text is easy, inspect the nav item I think the wordpress active class is .current-menu-item so add css styling to this. In order to alter the height of the header you would need javascript.

Comment: Guess no code, no answers...

Answer (score 0):

To change the colour of the text:

```
.navbar-nav > .active:not(.btn) > a {
    color: insert-color-here !important;
}
```

For the header, please try the below code:

```
.page-header.header-small .container {
    padding-top: 180px !important;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately current-menu-item doesn't work.
url is: www.elans.gr

Comment: It seems your site has .active as a class. See the new code I have edited my answer @MariosT.